# How to find the first differentials between elements in a list of list?

Tags: math, for-loop, python-2.7

I have a list of list as follow:

```
data = [
[0.051, 0.05],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[0.03],
[0.048],
[],
[0.037, 0.036, 0.034, 0.032],
[0.033, 0.032, 0.03]
]
```

I am trying to find the first difference between the elements in each sub-list but couldn't quite figure out how to do so with python. Here's what i wrote:

```
x = {}
index = 0
for item in data:
    if len(item) < 2:
        x[index] = "NA"      
        index += 1
    else:
        try:
            x[index] = item[0] - item[1]
            index += 1        
        except IndexError:
            x[index] = "NA"
            index += 1
y = {}
index = 0
for item in data:
    if len(item) < 2:
        y[index] = "NA"      
        index += 1
    else:
        try:
            y[index] = item[1] - item[2]
            index += 1        
        except IndexError:
            y[index] = "NA"
            index += 1
z = {}
index = 0
for item in data:
    if len(item) < 2:
        z[index] = "NA"      
        index += 1
    else:
        try:
            z[index] = item[2] - item[3]
            index += 1        
        except IndexError:
            z[index] = "NA"
            index += 1
```

However, I would much prefer a more dynamic version that could extend based on the number of elements in each sub-list. Mathematically, there will be n - 1 first differential x for n elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [
[0.051, 0.05],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[0.03],
[0.048],
[],
[0.037, 0.036, 0.034, 0.032],
[0.033, 0.032, 0.03]
]

x = {}
for i in range(0,len(data)):
    tmp = []
    #print "\ndata[i]= ", data[i]
    try:
        z = 0
        for s in range(0,len(data[i])):
            try:
                z = str(data[i][s] - data[i][s+1])   #WITHOUT THIS STR() HERE VALUES GOT ROUNDED - so instead of getting 0.001 it was 0.000999999999994 or sth like that.
                #print "difference = ", z
                tmp.append(z)
                #print "tmp = ", tmp
            except:
                pass
                #print "inside error"
    except:
        pass
        #print "error"#, i
    x[i+1] = tmp

print x
```

Here is my working code. I hope it's what you meant.

----> v THIS IS FIXED v <----

I have only one problem with it - for example:

```
difference = 0.001
tmp = [0.000999999999999994]
```

difference (z variable) is appended to tmp, and tmp looks like "rounded" instead of full 0.001, I don't really know how to format it properly :(.

I will try work on it now and I will edit my post if I manage to do it somehow.

@@@@ FIX EDIT: @@@@@

I fixed it by changing the difference value to str instead of leaving it as float.

Comment: This is really brilliant. My code is just too long and not optimized.